# Number of leaves in any types of tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have to prove the following claim by induction, given any tree *T = ($V_T, E_T$)* with at least two vertices, the number of leaves is given by

$$
|V_1| = 2 - \sum(j-2)|V_j|
$$
where the sum is from $j=3$ up to the highest degree, and
$$
V_i = [x\in V |deg(x)=i]
$$

When I was doing this question I found it is trivial, but do not know how to say is mathematically.

Can someone help out with a hint?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Base case: verify the formula holds for the tree with two vertices.

Induction case: assume the formula holds for any tree with $n-1$ vertices. Now consider a tree with $n$ vertices. If you delete a leaf, you get a tree with $n - 1$ vertices, so the formula holds for this smaller tree. Can you use that to prove the formula also holds for the original tree on $n$ vertices?

---

Update:

Suppose $T$ has $\ge 3$ vertices.
Let $T'=(V', E')$ be the result of deleting a leaf $v$ from $T$. Two things change: (a) a leaf is removed, and (b) the neighbor of $v$ has its degree reduced by $1$.

### Case 1: the neighbor of $v$ has degree $> 2$.

Suppose the neighbor of $v$ has degree $j^*$ in $T$; then in $T'$, it has degree $j^*-1 \ge 2$. Therefore, we have $$|V'_1| = |V_1| - 1$$ (the deletion decreases the number of leaves by $1$), as well as $$|V'_{j^*}| = |V_{j^*}| - 1$$ and $$|V'_{j^*-1}| = |V_{j^*-1}| + 1.$$ For $j \notin \{1, j^*-1, j^*\}$, we have $|V'_{j}| = |V_j|$.

By induction we know $|V'_1| = 2 - \sum_{j=3}^{d_{\max}} (j-2) |V'_j|$. Adding $1$ to the left-hand side, and adding $(j^*-2) - (j^* - 1- 2)=1$ to the right-hand side yields $|V_1| = 2 - \sum_{j=3}^{d_{\max}} (j-2) |V_j|$.

### Case 2: the neighbor of $v$ has degree $2$.

Here, we simply have $|V'_2| = |V_2| - 1$. We have $|V'_j| = |V_j|$ for all $j \ne 2$. (Note that the number of leaves does not change, because the deletion removes the leaf $v$, but its neighbor becomes a new leaf.)

By induction we know $|V'_1| = 2 - \sum_{j=3}^{d_{\max}} (j-2) |V'_j|$. Substituting $|V_j|=|V'_j|$ for all $j \ne 2$ yields $|V_1| = 2 - \sum_{j=3}^{d_{\max}} (j-2) |V_j|$.

Comment: Hi, I did not get what are you talking about : (